# File downloading via FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, ftp

I am trying to download the .xml file from ftp server to my computer, but I always take an error as System.UnauthorizedAccessException: `C:\users\...\mypath` access denied.

How can I fix the problem that clearly? I am trying to change target folder as a removable harddrive unfortunately I got same exception. Besides I can not change folder properties which is read-only state, Where I was make the mistake I can not obtain that. Can you help for the figured it out the problem and fix it?

The console said that `FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);` code part is mistaken.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace GetXMLNodes
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ftp ftpClient = new ftp(@"ftp://...ip", "username", "password");
            ftpClient.download(@"3636594381842_2015-04-08T12_08_27.177Z Status.xml", @"C:\Users\HIKMET\Desktop\Proje_XML_to_SCADA\DownloadedXML");
            ftpClient = null;
            Console.WriteLine("download success..!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}



class ftp
{
    private string host = null;
    private string user = null;
    private string pass = null;
    private FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
    private FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
    private Stream ftpStream = null;
    private int bufferSize = 2048;

    /* Construct Object */
    public ftp(string hostIP, string userName, string password) { host = hostIP; user = userName; pass = password; }

    /* Download File */
    public void download(string remoteFile, string localFile)
    {
        try
        {
            /* Create an FTP Request */
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
            /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            /* When in doubt, use these options */
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
            ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            /* Open a File Stream to Write the Downloaded File */
            //FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write,localFile);
            //f.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.Write;
            //f.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write | FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, localFile);
            //f.Demand();
            FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
            /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            /* Download the File by Writing the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
            try
            {
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    localFileStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            /* Resource Cleanup */
            localFileStream.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpResponse.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        return;
    }
```

}

Comment: You said the folder was read only and you can't change that, but you're trying to save a new file into it and getting an unauthorised access exception. What happens when you save somewhere that you'll always have access like Documents, does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I got same error, same exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `localFile` is a directory:

```
@"C:\Users\HIKMET\Desktop\Proje_XML_to_SCADA\DownloadedXML"
```

Attempting I/O on a directory path will raise `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Provide a file name in the `download()` call.

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand what you mean, I have already provide file name into `download()` call as `@"C:\Users\HIKMET\Desktop\Proje_XML_to_SCADA\DownloadedXML"`, sorry for misunderstanding, could you explain the solution with more details?

Comment: So `DownloadedXML` is the file name? as opposed to `C:\Users\HIKMET\Desktop\Proje_XML_to_SCADA\DownloadedXML\something.xml` ?